# How can I filter children properties by parent property in Angular JS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How can I filter the below JSON object so that I only display names that have a date of '01-2015'? When I try using the filter method below I end up getting what looks like "[] []" in the HTML content. If there is a solution, how can I display each array item of names instead of having the HTML return ['Susan Hill', 'Petrona Morgan']?

```
var annApp = angular.module('anniversaries', []);

<div ng-app="anniversaries" class="row" ng-controller="annList">
<div class="mdl-card__supporting-text text2" >
    <p ng-repeat="ann in anns">{{ ann.names | filter:{$:"01-2015"} }}</p>
</div>
<script>
annApp.controller('annList', function ($scope) {
  $scope.anns = [
    {'date':'01-2015','year': '45', 
    'names': ['Susan Hill', 'Petrona Morgan ']},
    {'date': '01-2015', 'year': '35',
    'names': ['Terisa Branson', 'Jo Fox', 'Genette McKown']}
  ];
}); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
<p ng-repeat="ann in anns | filter: {date : '01-2015'}">
  <span ng-repeat="name in ann.names">{{name}}<br/></span>
</p>
```

Comment: Looks like I just added the filter in the wrong spot. Thanks. Would you happen to know how I could display all of the names without the array brackets? So instead of the text displaying as ['name,'name'] it would display as "name name"?

Comment: This does not seem to output any text.

Comment: What it is showing ? Check your console too please.

Comment: Console is clear. ann.names works in the first paragraph but name does not work in the second.

Comment: I figured it out. You cannot have a paragraph inside of another paragraph, but you can use a span tag and this does the trick. Thanks for your help @Vineet.

Comment: Your always welcome dude :) Yeah, I was thinking the same. You can accept this as an aswer :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89094/discussion-between-coded-container-and-vineet).